# Makefile: setting variables only for one target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have following makefile:

```
.PHONY: backup other

REMOTE_HOST := server1
DOMAIN_NAME := vm1

VM_IS_RUNNING := $(shell ssh $(REMOTE_HOST) virsh domstate "$(DOMAIN_NAME)")

ifneq ($(.SHELLSTATUS),  0)
    $(error SSH command failed with status $(.SHELLSTATUS))
endif

################################################################################

backup:

ifeq ($(VM_IS_RUNNING),running)

    @echo "VM $(DOMAIN_NAME) is running."
    @exit 0

else

    @echo "VM $(DOMAIN_NAME) is NOT running."
    @exit 0

endif

################################################################################

other:

    @echo "hello"
```

first, I am setting some variables which are later used in target `backup`, then I have target `backup` itself, and last I have another unrelated target `other`.

How can I run target `other` without setting the connection variables which I need for my first target ?

I tried moving those inside the backup section, but did not work

Comment: This looks like a job for [target-specific variable values](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific). Do you want to use all three variables in the `other` rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compute the values only in the `backup` command, then you should compute the values only in the `backup` command.  Remove the `VM_IS_RUNNING` make variable assignment, and change `backup` to perform the operation as part of the recipe:

```
backup:
    @running=$$(ssh $(REMOTE_HOST) virsh domstate "$(DOMAIN_NAME)") || exit 1; \
    if test "$$running" = running; then \
        echo "VM $(DOMAIN_NAME) is running."; \
    else \
        echo "VM $(DOMAIN_NAME) is NOT running."; \
    fi
```

Comment: thank you. I think the `@` at the start of the 3rd line is a typo?. When I remove it, it works. But where do I put the check whether `ssh` command returned error? `ifneq ($(.SHELLSTATUS),  0)
    $(error SSH command failed with status $(.SHELLSTATUS))
endif` in my original code. I don't want to continue further, if server cannot be reached.

Comment: I updated the recipe.  Just check the exit of the `ssh` and exit early if you see it.